# vb message display

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

when I click on the register button I get the test `"registration successful"` even if I didn't enter anything on the column.
I need to display `"registration successful"` if it successfully inserted to the database.
if it is a failure I need it to display `"registration fail"` on the same label (`lblsuccessfail`)

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.IO

Partial Class register
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page


    Dim cn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost\MSSQL2012;Initial Catalog=UserDetails;Integrated Security=True")
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter


    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnnew.Click
        cn.Open()


        Try


            Dim Query As String

            Query = "INSERT INTO FirstProject (fullname,username,password,address,gender)VALUES('" & txtfullname.Text & "', '" & txtusername.Text & "','" & txtpassword.Text & "','" & txtaddress.Text & "','" & cbogender.Text & "')"

            cmd = New SqlCommand(Query, cn)


            If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() Then

                lblsuccessfail.Text = lblsuccessfail.Text & " Registertration successful "

            End If

        Catch ex As Exception

            lblsuccessfail.Text = lblsuccessfail.Text & " Registertration unsuccessful "


        End Try

        cn.Close()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnback_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnback.Click
        Response.Redirect("login.aspx")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery returns the number of rows inserted so, if your database accepts an empty  record, your code is always succesful. You need to add checks for this eventuality  in code or in the database itself. By the way, your code will never compile if had enabled Option Strict On warning you of the problem with ExecuteNonQuery and do yourself a favor. Learn how to use a parameterized query.

Comment: If you add nothing to the text box, it still saves null. Your code do not check any value before inserting it. Read about null values, and add conditions to check them.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.IO

Partial Class register
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page


    Dim cn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost\MSSQL2012;Initial Catalog=UserDetails;Integrated Security=True")
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter


    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnnew.Click
        Try

            cn.Open()


            cmd = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO FirstProject (fullname,username,password,address,gender)VALUES('" & txtfullname.Text & "', '" & txtusername.Text & "','" & txtpassword.Text & "','" & txtaddress.Text & "','" & cbogender.Text & "')", cn)

            If txtfullname.Text = Nothing OrElse txtusername.Text IsNot Nothing Or txtpassword.Text.Equals(Nothing) OrElse txtaddress.Text = String.Empty Or cbogender.Text.Equals(String.Empty) Then Throw New Exception()

            If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() Then lblsuccessfail.Text = lblsuccessfail.Text & " Registertration successful "

        Catch ex As Exception

            lblsuccessfail.Text = lblsuccessfail.Text & " Registertration unsuccessful "

        Finally
            cn.Close()
        End Try

    End Sub

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnback_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnback.Click
        Response.Redirect("login.aspx")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Now it will be an unsuccessful registration if the columns are blank.